# Displaying Saved Data Outside of Loop

Tags: matlab

Below is my current MATLAB code. The code functions properly but I want to know if there is a way to display the data outside of the loop while it updates. ThingSpeak is one current method I am using but I would like to see it in MATLAB as well.

```
a = Bluetooth('HC-05',1);

a.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';

fopen(a);

heartRateVar=0;
temperatureVar=0;
accVar=0;

while (a.Status == 'open')

    rawData = fscanf(a,'%s');    

    idx = strfind(rawData,'_');
    match = strtrim(rawData(1:idx-1));

    test = strncmpi(match,'Celsius',2);

    if(test==1)
        temperatureVar=match;
    elseif(test==0)
        if(strncmpi(match,'BPM',2)==1)
        heartRateVar=match;
        end
    end

%create arbitrary time stamps of same size as data points to send data 
to thingspeak

stamps = [datetime('now')-minutes(length(match)-1):minutes(1):datetime('now')]';

%send data accompanied by timestamps to thingspeak
thingSpeakWrite(501358,{heartRateVar,temperatureVar,accVar},'WriteKey','JLS6DXUINWFGI6QD');

if(a.Status ~= 'open')
   break;
end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use debug mode by setting a break point on the variable line and run your code or you can print it on the screen